# ShowDuration attribute cannot resolve in tooltip at silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

i want use to ShowDuration attribute in a tooltip at silverlight project. but ShowDuration not exist in ToolTip control

for example:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAppUserRoleAdd" Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" Content="button" Width="100" Height="36" Margin="0 0 40 0">
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip ShowDuration="10000" Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}" HorizontalOffset="2" VerticalOffset="5">
                        <ToolTip.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="any test" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTooltipFontStyle}" />
                        </ToolTip.Content>
                    </ToolTip>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

"ShowDuration="10000" this attribute have not known by intellisence in VS2010 and that say: cannot resolve symbol ShowDuration

my tooltip without ShowDuration working properly and not problem. but i want use this attribute. of course, i use tooltip class in code (c#) but problem not solved.

please help me
i use silverlight4, visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 3):

The Silverlight implementation of a `ToolTip` does not have a `ShowDuration` property.

Comment: thanks Anthony. but please check this links: [http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/101711.aspx](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/101711.aspx), [link 2](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2009/06/23/Silverlight-ToolTipService-set-the-ToolTip-display-time-%28part-2-a-closer-look%29.aspx), [http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/19855/338900.aspx](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/19855/338900.aspx), [http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/84615.aspx](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/84615.aspx)

Comment: @Hamed:  That just goes to show you that you can't believe everything you read on the web.  All those examples are wrong or out of date.  A better place to get a definitive answer would be the actual documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=VS.95).aspx See any mention of ShowDuration there?  Alternatively just use the object browser in VS2010 to inspect the available members of the ToolTip.  There is no ShowDuration.

Comment: yes, i had seen msdn and i know **ShowDuration** dependency property not exist in tooltip control. but i see many examples in web who use **ShowDuration** and **InitialDelay** in tooltip and even some of the this examples have a demo and those work properly!. i want just have a time delay and showing time in my tooltip. have you a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The referenced Tooltip opensource lib has big problem when use with Silverlight DataGrid control, it open many tooltips which are not closed when mouse moved away, it can open many of the same tooltips if you you move mouse arround in a cell.  We are forced to take it out from project.  We are still looking for a solution just to extend the display duration of tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com/) is a Advanced Silverlight Tooltip Control. This Tooltip has the **DisplayTime** property. Maybe it is helpful.
 You have to download the dll file and reference it.

Comment: thanks dear **Mrainy**. i already used this dll, but i have myself template for my tooltip and could not use this component. i want just have a time delay and showing time in my tooltip. have you other solution?

Comment: @hamed ajorloo. The ShowDuration property belongs to Tooltipservice, not tooltip. Further more, only the .NET Framework 4 supports this property. I didn't find more useful solution in the current release Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight tooltips currently don't have the extended functionality that WPF provide to set delay or duration.

As much as I'd like to see this functionality baked into Silverlight, I've had to build something myself. This also meant I had to create my own ToolTipService as lots of the code I needed to hook into was internal.

Replace your references to ToolTipService and ToolTip to the ones in the library and you'll get more properties to exploit :-)

You can find it on [Codeplex](http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com) as well as on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/Silverlight.Advanced.ToolTips).
Hope that helps!

Cheers,
Xavier