# Silverlight tooltip - change ShowDuration lightweight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, tooltip

Hi I am trying to change `ShowDuration` of tooltip and this is not supported in silverlight.
I dont want a heavyweight tooltip solution that is available on codeplex. My current idea is to edit something in tooltip template.

I looked with reflector and wasn't able to find default duration in tooltip so I think its being set in xaml. ( probably in storyboard for open tooltip event)

default tooltip style is given here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334410(VS.95).aspx.

there are two storyboard keys present in it but where can I find their implementation and override?

If someone posted template with for example infinite duration tooltip I would be grateful.

This isn't a duplicate of this [ShowDuration attribute cannot resolve in tooltip at silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505308/showduration-attribute-cannot-resolve-in-tooltip-at-silverlight-4) cause I am mainly looking for those 2 storyboards to edit them myself, not to mention other question isn't really answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about it unless you create your own `ToolTipService` (note its this service class not the ToolTip itself that is the problem).  The 5 second limit is baked into the code, it has nothing to do with the Storyboards.

If you want see this for yourself in Reflector open the ToolTipService class and look at the `OpenAutomaticTooltip` method.

Comment: thanks. indeed I didn't find the real root of that 5 sec TimeSpan. can only wonder why they didn't include a property for that.